# Limpar um variável do Bean pela página JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Tenho uma página com alguns laços de iteração dentro da minha página `JSF` e aí gostaria de saber como faço para após cada laço limpar esse atributo da página.

Para ser mais claro, eu sei que ao renderizar uma página as vezes um método é chamado algumas vezes, então se cria uma `lista` por exemplo e a preenche se estiver vazia.

```
public List<Long> buscarLojas() {
    if (NullUtil.isNull(this.idsLoja)) {
        this.idsLoja = new ArrayList<Long>(this.getPojo().getRelatorioExtratoLojista().keySet());
    }
    return idsLoja;
}
```

No código acima é feito isso, mas eu gostaria de saber se tem como limpar após sair da execução do laço `ui:repeat`

Segue meu código da página, esta omitido a maioria das colunas.

```
<ui:param name="lojas" value="#{bean.buscarLojas()}"/>
<ui:repeat var="loja" value="#{lojas}">
    <ui:param name="filiais" value="#{bean.buscarFilial(loja)}" />
    <ui:repeat var="filial" value="#{filiais}">
        <ui:param name="atendentes" value="#{bean.buscarAtendente(loja, filial)}" />
        <ui:repeat var="atendente" value="#{atendentes}">
            <ui:param name="propostasStatus" value="#{bean.buscarPropostaStatus(loja, filial, atendente)}" />
            <ui:repeat var="propostaStatus" value="#{propostasStatus}">
                <ui:param name="objetos" value="#{bean.buscarObjeto(loja, filial, atendente, propostaStatus)}" />
                <p:panelGrid
                    id="panelGridRelatorioExtratoLojista" 
                    styleClass="panelGridCenter gridNoBackground" 
                    style="width: 100%; white-space:nowrap;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnLeft" colspan="12">
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{bean.criarTituloTabela(objetos[0][4], objetos[0][5], objetos[0][6], objetos[0][3])}"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Classificação"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ui:repeat var="objeto" value="#{objetos}">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{objeto[7]}"/>
                            </p:column>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <br/>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

A estrutura que abriga os dados é essa:

```
private Map<Long, Map<Long, Map<Long, Map<Integer, List<Object>>>>> map;
```

Comment: Oi Macario, você poderia esclarecer o que você quer dizer por limpar? Parece que você está construindo uma lista de IDs em cima das chaves de um mapa. Você gostaria de limpar o mapa?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly eu atualizei o código, como eu disse no texto, muita das vezes vou ficar acessando os métodos na página. E gostaria de a cada chamada dos métodos na página, passar para uma lista, assim que terminar o laço dessa lista, limpar a lista para ela pegar o novo conteúdo, isso tem mais haver com a perfomance na questão da renderização da página `JSF`.

Comment: Olá Macario, pelo que entendi você quer usar um `map.clear()` depois de construir a lista, isso resolveria o problema? Fora do assunto principal, mas será que sua estrutura com quatro mapas aninhados não poderia ser substituída por algo mais orientado a objetos? Em Java é sempre estranho ver algo assim.

Comment: Cara vc entendeu errado, seria o seguinte, imagina a seguinte situação, vc tem um componente que carrega uma lista a partir de dados do banco. Agora imagina que ao renderizar esse componente, esse método vai ser chamado por exemplo 2 ou 3 vezes, então vai ser chamado 3 vezes no banco, então por isso eu uso a lista para não sobrecarregar, entendeu?

Comment: Sobre a questão da orientação a objetos, é que o objeto em questão tem esses atributos mas a forma como essa tabela é construída me fez criar essa estrutura.

Comment: Opa Macario. Eu acho que o que está fazendo sua questão ficar confusa é o design. Parece que seu código está invertendo o MVC, a *view* inteligente está chamando vários métodos aninhados no bean para construir os dados, agora você quer que a *view* também notifique o bean após o último `<ui:repeat` para limpar a lista `idLojas`. É isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32669/discussion-between-macario1983-and-anthony-accioly).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly veja o chat por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumo da conversa com o OP [no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32669/discussion-between-macario1983-and-anthony-accioly)

#### Problema original: Limpar os dados

O OP estava armazenando todos os dados da consulta e as várias projeções em um Managed Bean `@SessionScoped`. O consumo de memória estava batendo em mais de 1.5GB, gerando um markup de mais de 130 MB para um único request. O tempo de renderização chegava a mais de 10 minutos.

O requisito original do OP era que os filtros fossem mantidos através de requests, dessa forma recomendei a seguinte solução:

- `FiltroPropostaBean` -> Contém Apenas parâmetros do filtro armazenados em sessão (novo Managed Bean)
- `PropostasBean` -> Bean `Request` ou `ViewScoped` que utiliza os dados do bean de Filtro para fazer a consulta.

Com essa estrutura os dados só vivem tempo o suficiente para serem renderizados, evitando desperdício de memória.

### Modelo e projeções

O código original do OP utilizava uma estratégia com `ResultTransformer` para criar uma projeção:

```
Map<Long, Map<Long, Map<Long, Map<Integer, List<Object>>>>> map;
```

Essa era a saída pura de uma *query* após aplicados os respectivos [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html)s.

Como essa estrutura não era facilmente navegável pelo OP, ele acabou criando várias projeções da projeção. Eis o motivo do método `buscarLojas`, `buscarFilial`, etc. Com cinco *repeaters* aninhados esses métodos eram chamados várias vezes, com grande impacto de processamento.

Dessa forma, a questão do OP tinha mais a ver com design do que qualquer outra coisa.

Organizando os dados com *DTOs* é possível escrever código mais simples para a view, bem como remover os métodos de projeção.

E.g., um único método que retorne uma `List<GrupoPropostasDTO>`.

```
class GrupoPropostaDTO {
    private Loja loja; 
    private Filial filial; 
    private Atendente atendente;
    private Loja<Proposta> propostas; 
    // Getters and setters
}
```

Resolve ambos os problemas. Essa transformação pode ser feita em uma camada intermediaria de serviços ou em um `@PostConstruct` de `ProspotaBean`. Dessa forma uma única transformação é feita por *request* e a *view* não quebra o MVC chamando métodos para calcular projeções.

### Paginação

Finalmente, mesmo com os DTOs a quantidade de dados ainda é massiva. Isso pode ser resolvido com [Paginação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination).

### Boas Práticas

Enquanto versões modernas do JSF permitem o uso de vários artifícios interessantes, é bom ponderar antes de utilizar algo que quebre o padrão MVC, bem como boas práticas de desenvolvimento:

- Mantenha a camada de *view* burra. Dentro do possível o papel da view deve ser apenas exibir dados, fazer chamadas para métodos complexos na view é um *bad smell*.
- Escolha o escopo correto. Quanto menos estado melhor. Nem tudo pode ser feito de maneira 100% Stateless, porém o escopo de sessão não deve ser a escolha padrão.
- Projete bem a sua camada de modelo. Um bom modelo resolve 99% dos seus problemas.
- Controllers (ou, no caso de JSF a camada de cola nos *managed beans*) deve permanecer simples. Controllers pesados são sintomas de *views* fazendo mais do que devem e camada de serviços / modelo mal projetadas.

Comment: Estou com uma dúvida pelo seguinte, o sistema implementa `Spring` pra injeção de dependências. Isso é feito em arquivos diferentes, o problema é que eu setei no arquivo do `filter`, a classe como `session`, e no arquivo da `view` eu coloquei como `request` mas ao efetuar a pesquisa, parece que a classe dos dados do filtro se perde. Como corrigir isso?

Comment: Oi Macário. Vale abrir mais uma nova pergunta. Você deveria ter um escopo só para o Filter (Session). A classe de request apenas injeta o filter e refaz a consulta.

Comment: Feito! Obrigado.